# How to run two requests parallel in django rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-celery, django-request

I have two requests, which are called from react front end, one request is running in a loop which is returning image per request, now the other request is registering a user, both are working perfect, but when the images request is running in a loop, at the same time I register user from other tab,but that request status shows pending, if I stops the images request then user registered,How can I run them parallel at the same time.

**urls.py**

```
  url(r'^create_user/$', views.CreateUser.as_view(), name='CreateAbout'),
   url(r'^process_image/$', views.AcceptImages.as_view(), name='AcceptImage'),
```

**Views.py**

```
class CreateUser(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        return Response([UserSerializer(dat).data for dat in User.objects.all()])

    def post(self,request):
        payload=request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=payload)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            instance = serializer.save()
            instance.set_password(instance.password)
            instance.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class AcceptImages(APIView):

    def post(self,request):
        global video

        stat, img = video.read()
        frame = img
        retval, buffer_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        resdata = base64.b64encode(buffer_img)

        return Response(resdata)
```

These endpoints I am calling from react,the second endpoint is being calling in a loop and the same time from other tab I register user but it shows status pending and If I stop the image endpoint it then register the user,how can I make these two request run parallel.
I have researched a lot but can't find appropriate solution, there is one solution I using celery, but did not whether it solves my problem if it solves how can I implement above scenerio

Answer (score 2):

You should first determine whether the bottleneck is the frontend or the backend.

- frontend: Chrome can make up to 6 requests for the same domain at a time. (Up to HTTP/1.1)
- backend: If you use `python manage.py runserver`, consider using gunicorn or uWSGI. As the [Django documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver), the manage.py command should not be used in production. Modify the process and thread count settings in the gunicorn or uWSGI to 2 or higher and try again.